# Is it true that every locally compact Polish space must be boundedly compact?

Tags: general-topology

My question: Is it true that every locally compact Polish space must be boundedly compact?

Explanation of terminology:

- Locally compact: Every point admits a compact neighborhood;
- Polish space: Complete, separable metric space;
- Boundedly compact: Every closed and bounded subset is compact.

It seems that this fact is used in Villani's book *Optimal transport, old and new*, e.g. in the proof of Proposition 27.24 and the convention in p.763-764.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: "boundedly compact" seems to be "has the [Heine-Borel property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine-Borel_theorem#Heine%E2%80%93Borel_property)".

Answer (score 0):

No. Take any infinite discrete space $X$, which is itself closed and bounded and for every point $x$, $\{x\}$ is a compact neighbourhood containing $x$. $X$ isn't compact, however, as the compacts subsets of $X$ are the finite ones.

Comment: Thanks for your timely answer and illuminating example. This also makes it clear to me why there is a seemingly strange additional condition (closure of any open ball with radius r coincides with the closed ball with radius r) in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413485/a-locally-compact-complete-metric-space-in-which-the-closure-of-open-balls-coin.

Answer (score 0):

Another example ...
The interval $(0,1)$ with the usual topology.
It is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, so it is Polish and locally compact.
But the whole space $(0,1)$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

---

Unlike the OP, I used the usual definition of "Polish space", namely: **homeomorphic to** a complete separable metric space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I guess the point is that the Heine-Borel property is not a topological property. Thus we can change the metric on the real line into a bounded one, preserving all the topological property while breaking the bounded compactness.